# Concat Column A and B as value of Column C in access

Tags: ms-access

What I get on Google's search results are on creating a query.
What I am looking for is an excel like function, though I use MS Access.
[image]
How am I able to automatically get a concatenated `Week & SowOrder` appear on `EN`?
`0101`
`0102`
I use 2010 Access but 2003 format.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate those fields in a query.

```sql
SELECT [Week], SowOrder, [Week] & SowOrder AS EN
FROM YourTable;
```

Then you can use the query anytime you need to see `EN`.

If you need to store those concatenated values in your table, you can use an `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET EN = [Week] & SowOrder;
```

However, storing the values means you need to remember to execute the `UPDATE` again any time the `Week` or `SowOrder` values change.

Note you could use `+` instead of `&` for concatenation.  The difference between those two operators is how they behave with Null:

- `"foo" & Null` yields `"foo"`
- `"foo" + Null` yields `Null`

Comment: one thing, when I do solution 1, which is what I tried earlier, it doesn't count zero as a number. Therefore, 01 & 01 = 11. Another thing, since you need to call this, its not automatic like how they use it on excel? I was just finding an easy way around inside access that can do that for my program, but I guess, I need to do it in the code. Even still, thanks.

Comment: I thought both those fields (Week and SowOrder) are text datatype.  If they are numeric, perhaps they are formatted to display as 01 instead of just 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd get the leading zeros from each field to display if they are of number types, or if your data would change to '10', '11', '12'...'41','42','43.. and so on.

However, if Fields 1 and 2 are text, Field three would be a Calculated field as

```
=[week]&[SowOrder]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, use + sign to concatenate in your case
[Calculated field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-HA101820564.aspx)

Comment: I need it **concatenated**, not calculated.

Comment: @AdorableVB - technically, Usman's answer will also work since it looks like `Week` and `SowOrder` are both text data type columns (your question doesn't specify). In Access SQL you can use `+` to concatenate two bits of text.

Answer (score 0):

Building on HansUp's answer, you probably want

```
SELECT [Week], [SowOrder], Format([Week],"00") & Format([SowOrder],"00") AS EN
```

The Format functions will force the inclusion of leading zeroes on any single-digit numbers.